# How to create an instance method based on this object data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some data inside this variable and I want to know how could I write an method to give me the sum of the items price.

Model names and their associations:

```
Order
- belongs_to :customer
- has_many :item_orders
- has_many :items, :through => :item_orders
- accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_orders, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a['item_id'].blank? }


Item
- has_many :item_orders, :dependent => :destroy
- has_many :orders, :through => :item_orders
- accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_orders, :allow_destroy => true

ItemOrder
- belongs_to :item
- belongs_to :order
```

doing:

```
<%= debug @order.items %> 

# returns me

- !ruby/object:Item
  attributes:
  id: 31
  title: Golden Ring 2
  price: 13445.0
  labour_cost: 500.0
  item_type_id: 10
  created_at: 2011-08-13 10:53:24.000000000Z
  updated_at: 2011-08-18 06:10:36.000000000Z
  photo: golden_ring.jpg
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
- !ruby/object:Item
 attributes:
  id: 32
  title: Special Pendant
  price: 171.67
  labour_cost: 120.0
  item_type_id: 20
  created_at: 2011-08-13 11:09:43.000000000Z
  updated_at: 2011-08-14 06:03:02.000000000Z
  photo: prd_194_48cd9b21771dd.jpg
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
```

So, I want to write a method in the `Order` model class to make possible writes something like this on the view.

```
 <%= @order.items.total_price %>
```

The `total_price` method will sum all the item prices and multiply by the quantity that contains in `@order.items`.

My doubt is: from inside the method, how could I have access to the `items` collection to perform the sum operation.

```
def total_price
  self.item_order.each do |i| { 
     result += i.quantity * i.items.price
  }
end
```

**EDIT: I totally forgot to mention that I have to consider the quantity also to make this** math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible approaches.

1) Use ActiveRecord `sum`. This is efficient as the SUM operation is performed in the DB. When  you are dealing with 100s of rows this is the way to go:

```
items.sum(:price)  # executes select sum(items.price) 
                   #          from items where items.order_id = some_id
```

2) Use Enumeration `sum`. Here you are operating on an existing array.

```
items.to_a.sum(&:price)
```

I use this approach when my `has_many association` list size is small( < 10) and already eager loaded.

**Edit 1: Based on additional requirement**

Using ActiveRecord:

```
item_orders.sum("item_orders.quantity * item.price", :join => :item)
```

Using Enumeration

```
item_orders.all(:include => :item).sum {|io| io.quantity * io.item.price }
```

Comment: Updated the answer. take a look.

Comment: I have tested it and it works. Make sure you are using the correct association names. It was not clear if the name of the line items association is `item_order` or `order_items`. What is the error you got?

Comment: I name it wrong so it is `item_order`. The `quantity` attribute belongs to the `order` table and others to `item` table.

Comment: Can you provide the model names and their associations.

Comment: I have updated the answer. It should work assuming you have  `quantity` column in `item_orders` table.

Answer (score 2):

define a function in order.rb like this:

```
def total_price
  self.items.inject(0) {|sum, item| sum + item.price }
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= @order.total_price %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= @order.items.inject(0) {|sum, item| sum + item.price} %>`

Comment: Thanks! Although this works, I really like to know how could I implement that method. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you have `has_many :items` in your Order model, you should be able to use that **items** variable easily. All you need to do is write this in your Order model:

```
def total_price
  items.to_a.sum {|item| item.price}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could just do;

```
def total_price
  items.sum(:price)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In my `order.rb` I've created the `total_price` method.

```
def total_price
  self.item_orders.to_a.sum { |item| item.full_price }
end
```

and then, in my `item_order.rb`:

```
def full_price
  quantity * self.item.price
end
```

This does what I need. Thank you all !